# Integrate baselinker in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I need to send orders from file csv to baselinker in python.
I create with selenium script where I save information with orders from admin shop panel to csv file

Now i need to send informatiom from csv to baselinker API
I can create object from csv files with new orders

But i dont know how to connect it with Python and send it to Baselinker

Example in PHP:

```
<?php
$methodParams = '{
    "order_status_id": "6624",
    "date_add": "1495963282",
    "user_comments": "komentarz u\u017cytkownika",
    "admin_comments": "testowe uwagi sprzedawcy",
    "phone": "693123123",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "user_login": "nick1",
    "currency": "PLN",
    "payment_method": "PayU",
    "payment_method_cod": "0",
    "paid": "1",
    "delivery_method": "List polecony priorytetowy",
    "delivery_price": "10",
    "delivery_fullname": "Jan Kowalski",
    "delivery_company": "Firma",
    "delivery_address": "D\u0142uga 12",
    "delivery_city": "Wroc\u0142aw",
    "delivery_postcode": "51-113",
    "delivery_country_code": "PL",
    "delivery_point_id": "",
    "delivery_point_name": "",
    "delivery_point_address": "",
    "delivery_point_postcode": "",
    "delivery_point_city": "",
    "invoice_fullname": "Jan Kowalski",
    "invoice_company": "Firma",
    "invoice_nip": "PL8943245",
    "invoice_address": "D\u0142uga 12",
    "invoice_city": "Wroc\u0142aw",
    "invoice_postcode": "51-113",
    "invoice_country_code": "PL",
    "want_invoice": "0",
    "extra_field_1": "test pola 1",
    "extra_field_2": "",
    "products": [
        {
            "storage": "db",
            "storage_id": 0,
            "product_id": "5434",
            "variant_id": 52124,
            "name": "Harry Potter i kamie\u0144 filozoficzny",
            "sku": "LU4235",
            "ean": "1597368451236",
            "price_brutto": 20,
            "tax_rate": 23,
            "quantity": 2,
            "weight": 1
        }
    ]
}';
$apiParams = [
    "token" => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", 
    "method" => "addOrder", 
    "parameters" => $methodParams
];

$curl = curl_init("https://api.baselinker.com/connector.php");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($apiParams));   
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

What it should look like in Python. How convert this example to Python

//EDIT
I create script what show Orders:

```
import requests

data = {
  'token': 'TOKEN',
  'method': 'getOrders',
  'parameters': '{"date_from": 1407341754}'
}

response = requests.post('https://api.baselinker.com/connector.php', data=data)

print(response)

show=response.json()
print(show)
```

But now have problem how to add more methodParams not in one line?

Second Edit I create something like this:

```
 import requests
import json

parametry={
     "order_id": 17432941
   }
parameters = json.dumps(parametry)

data = {
  'token': 'TOKEN',
  'method': 'getOrders',
  'parameters': parameters
}




response = requests.post('https://api.baselinker.com/connector.php', data=data)

print(response)

show=response.json()
print(show)
```

And it works, but i dont know it is the best idea?

Answer (score 1):

Python does have multi line strings, but better to use a dictionary, not a string

```
data = {
  'token': 'TOKEN',
  'method': 'getOrders',
  'parameters': {
     "date_from": 1407341754
   }
}
```

And change `data=data` in the post to `json=data`

Comment: <Response [200]>
{'status': 'ERROR', 'error_code': 'ERROR_EMPTY_TOKEN', 'error_message': 'No user token provided.'}

Something wrong

Comment: I assume that's related to `TOKEN`. Otherwise, it's not clear how making the parameter value a string vs an object would change that response (which shouldn't be a 200 code if you get an error)

Comment: Look at my Second Edit

Comment: Like I said, not clear why the parameters field needs to be a string

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
import json

parameters = {
  'token': token_value,
  'method': 'getOrders',
  'parameters': json.dumps({
        "date_confirmed_from": 1407341754,
        "get_unconfirmed_orders": False,
        "order_id": 11112233
   })
}

response = requests.post('https://api.baselinker.com/connector.php', data=parameters)
print(response)
show = response.json()
print(show)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).